# How do I know which user sent the message when GCM server sends message to the recipient

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have successfully implemented GCM server and I am getting message as well as notification on the recipient side.But how can I know which client sent that message.This is because while sending message to GCM from server we never include the key of client who sends the message.

Is there any way I could know the sender key.

What I am actually doing is as:
            1.sending the message from client app to the 3rd party server.
            2.storing the message in the 3rd party server.
            3.Sending the message to GCM from server.

This is how I am implementing the server side code to send message to GCM.

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$receive_id=$_POST['receiver_key'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$registrationIDs = array( $receive_id);


    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );

 $curl_result = curl_exec( $ch );
```

I have used HTTP Post request in the client side to send recipient key and the message.

And the below is the IntentService which I am using to receive the message.
This IntentService is fired from the Broadcast Receiver.

```
  import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Notification.Builder;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService{

    public GCMIntentService(String Iservice) {
        super(Iservice);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super("MyIntentService");

    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm=GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String mType=gcm.getMessageType(intent);   //Message received here.
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.e("Message recieved",msg+" ");          


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   //using notification manager to send notification
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Chats.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                               

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);              
        Builder builder  = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("New Message Arrived!");
        builder.setContentText(msg+"");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);                       
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());                   

    }

}
```

The receipent are getting messages but how do I know which user sent that message.

Comment: I think you can pass data to your server along with gcm request and server pings the google server to pass the relevant data to recipient application, which in turn uses the handling of data received through gcm and parsing that info can get the information of sender at recipient end.

Comment: This is a nice solution...Actually I thought of doing so but then I was wondering, GCM provides such a wonderful facility then why don't they provide the information of sender at recipient end nor they accept any information of sender while sending request to GCM.

Comment: sorry i was saying it like "pass data to your server along with gcm request"!
actually client app  communicates with a 3rd-party app server and client app doesn't itself triggers the gcm request, 3rd-party server does that and it tells the google that which "Registration-Id"(client app registered itself on google server and 3rd-party server saved it for future communication) to hit and that "reg-id" is used to identify the recipient. by the way sender will be same all the time i.e. 3rd-party server

Comment: I agree,that the sender is always the 3-rd party server.But my question is   "" after the message is sent to the recipient by the GCM server..how can the "recipient" know which user sent that message.  "" .This is my actual question.

Comment: so in that array "array( "message" => $message )", i think you can put the sender details too, try to put and then see what comes in response at broadcast receiver's end when gcm notification arrives.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ..that worked and finally I got exactly what I wanted.Post that in the answer ,I will mark it as accepted.